# error in creating structure

Tags: matlab, structure

In MATLAB, why does this work:

```
>> a.b(1) = struct('c', [1 2])
```

but not this?:

```
>> a.b(1) = struct('c', {1 2})
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

Is there a way around this? I know I could just do `a.b(1).c = {1 2}`, but I have other fields I want to add to `a`.

Comment: Works in FreeMat, but not correctly. Tried double braces? `struct('c', {{1 2}})`

Comment: @arne.b: Thanks, that was it! Didn't really think of adding the double braces :s Could you post your comment as an answer please, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess when MATLAB encounters the braces, it tries to deal the two elements of the cell array to two elements of a struct array. Consider

```
 a.b(1:2) = struct('c', {1 2})
```

This will assign a 2-element cell array to a single struct field:

```
struct('c', {{1 2}})
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because `struct('c', {1 2})` *isn't* doing what you (presumably) think it's doing - creating a structure with one field, `c`, with value `{1, 2}`.  Rather, it's creating a 1x2 structure array, whose first value (that is, `answer(1).c`) is 1, and whose second value (that is, `answer(2).c`) is 2.

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html, and read the paragraph "If value is a cell array..." for more information.

As other posters suggested, wrapping it in *double* curly brackets works.  Why?  Read that documentation that I just pointed you to, and walk through it using `{{1, 2}}` and you'll see that it works exactly as you want.